# Javascript nested function attribute inheritance

Tags: javascript, function, class, inheritance

Im trying to use an attribute of a function in the nested function but i don't know how, without passing the parent function.

example:

```
function foo() {
    this.baz = 'baz'
    this.bar = new bar()
}

function bar() {
    this.bla = 'bla'
}

bar.prototype.func = function() {
    console.log(...) // this should return 'baz' (attr baz of foo())
}
```

So far i tryed this:

```
function foo() {
    this.baz = 'baz'
    this.bar = new bar(this)
}

function bar(foo) {
    this.bla = 'bla'
    this.foo = foo
}
bar.prototype.func = function() {
    console.log(this.foo.baz)
}
```

Is there a good pattern to accomplish this? since my workaround is a mess

**EDIT:**

Since some of you wanted a more reallife exapmle:

```
function Game() {
    this.world = {
        x: 200,
        y: 300
    }
    this.players = {
        one: new Player()
        two: new Player()
    }
}

function Player() {
    this.size = {x:1,y:2}
    this.position = {
        x: world.x - this.size.x, // i need to access games world attribute
        y: 0
    }
}
```

But this isn't the only attribute of the Game class i need in the Player class..

Comment: This seems like half a question about how JavaScript scoping works and half a question about how inheritance works. Maybe if you give more of a real-life example, we could make better suggestions for a *good* way to do what you're trying to. As it stands now, my response would be "just pass a `foo` reference to `bar`.

Comment: In your exampe, `bar` doesn't inherit from `foo`. There's no prototypical attribute on `bar` that can access `foo`'s properties. What you're doing in your first example could amount for *dependency injection*, but no inheritance whatsoever.  Regarding the second example, there isn't inheritance either, but you're using `bar` as a decorator of `foo`, so you're able to do `this.foo.baz`. It's perfectly valid for this implementation of a decorator.

Comment: I am with @brianvaughn - the current seems fine, however it might not be depending on the actual need and there could, indeed, be a better way.

Comment: I agree with @brianvaughn regarding the need of a real life example. The current question doesn't explain what you're trying to do. If you want to use `baz` inside `bar` you can either use it as in your second snippet, or you can instance `foo` and everything you would do inside `bar`  as `this.method` you instead do `this.bar.method` from `foo`. God I hate these ubiquitous dummy varnames.

Comment: thanks for your comments.. i added a real life example

Comment: This isn't inheritance. Also, why do both the game and the players have position? At any rate, it seems it's more of an architectural problem - the initialisation of the state needs to be separated by the representation. One way is for `Game` to be passed in `world` and it instantiates both `Player`s by passing it in and this could all be done in the constructor of `Game`.

Comment: `world` is the size of the game (canvas) and `position` is the position of the player. it's something completely different. the problem is that i have some attributes which i need in both prototypes (like `world` or canvas) and i didn't know if its clean if i pass the whole game function to the player..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

You may want to read about [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). Given your updated example, it would be reasonable for you to pass a reference for `Game` to each of your `Player` instances like so:

```
function Game() {
    this.world = {
        x: 200,
        y: 300
    }
    this.players = {
        one: new Player(this),
        two: new Player(this)
    }
}

function Player(game) {
    this.game = game;
    this.size = {x:1,y:2}
    this.position = {
        x: game.world.x - this.size.x, // i need to access games world attribute
        y: 0
    }
}
Player.prototype.anotherFunction = function() {
  console.log(this.game); // Also has access to `this.game`
}
```

As Vld@ says, there are likely better ways to accomplish what you're trying to do in this example but I suspect this is a more general question.

**Original answer**

One way to accomplish what you're trying to do would be with inheritance, like so:

```
function Foo() {
  this.baz = 'baz';
}
function Bar() {
  this.bla = 'bla';
  Foo.call(this);
}
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);

console.log(new Bar().baz); // "baz"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. what about using `game` in players prototype? can i use it there too?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. But... I'll update my answer to reflect what I *think* you're asking

Comment: yes this was exactly what i was asking for. but now you had to store the game instance in an attribute, which is what i already had. so if this is the best way my question in answered. thanks for your help!

Comment: As some of us hinted initially, the "best way" depends on the specifics of the problem. It can also be subjective. :) This seems like a reasonable way of handling the problem you've described though. Good luck!

Comment: I'd disagree slightly with passing the whole `Game` object to the `Player`s. What they are only interested in is the size of the canvas, so they could certainly accept either that `Player = function(width) {this.position {x : width - this.size.x}}` or accept the whole canvas. What I'm more inclined to do, in fact, is for the player to accept just a plain object called `data` and `width` (or `x`, if you wish) is one property of it. This means that if the `Player` needs other stuff in the future, they would just be passed in as configuration.

Comment: Vld@ hints at a good point. It's typically best to pass the lowest-level thing you need because it makes your code more intuitive at a glance (e.g. *why* do I need this thing), it simplifies dependencies when you're mocking/stubbing for tests, and various other reasons. In this case I assumed you actually want to use `Game` for more than just the one thing we're talking...so I passed full game.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass the whole "Game" function to the "Player", and also you would like to maintain the privacy of some variables and allow some of the players methods to access it, I recomend the following:

```
function Game() {

    // Declare private variables as 'var' here

    this.world = {
        x: 200,
        y: 300
    }
    this.players = {
        one: new Player()
        two: new Player()
    }

    // The following players methods will have access to 
    // both public and private interface of Game 
    this.players.one.position = {
        x: this.world.x - this.players.one.size.x, 
        y: 0
    }
    this.players.two.position = this.players.one.position;
}

function Player() {
   // Declare private variables for player as 'var' here 

   this.size = {x:1,y:2}
}
```

Comment: and what about attibutes i need in player's prototype?

Comment: If your player prototype needs any attribute then you should pass it as a parameter to the constructor like this `one: new Player(specs)` (assuming your prototype methods are built using _this_ )